# Pattern match on Tuple2 of Success

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I have 2 `Future`s of `Try` and i want to do something only if both of them successfully complete. Both the `Future`s are independent. So here is some code

```
def a1: Future[Try[String]] = Future { Success("a1") }
def a2: Future[Try[Int]] = Future { Success(2) }

val r1 = for {
  c1 <- a1
  c2 <- a2
} yield (c1, c2)
r1.map {
  case tpl: (Success[String], Success[Int]) =>
    println("success")
  case _ =>
    println("failure")
}
```

This prints `success`.
The problem with this is because i am pattern matching on a `Tuple2`, because of erasure even if the second element is a `Failure` the first `case` is executed. So if i change `a2` to

```
def a2: Future[Try[Int]] = Future { Failure(new InternalError("error")) }
```

and then again execute this

```
val r1 = for {
  c1 <- a1
  c2 <- a2
} yield (c1, c2)
r1.map {
  case tpl: (Success[String], Success[Int]) =>
    println("success")
  case _ =>
    println("failure")
}
```

Now even when `a2` returns a `Failure` the above code still prints `success`. How do i fix this? A non pretty solution would be to check elements of the tuple using `isInstanceOf[Success[String]]` and `isInstanceOf[Success[Int]]` and act on their truth values but is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pattern match on tuple content:

```
r1.map {
  case (_: Success[String], _: Success[Int]) =>
    println("success")
  case _ =>
    println("failure")
}
```

This way it overcomes type erasure by calling tuple's `unapply` method, getting tuple elements and then checking their types. And tuple elements do have their runtime types intact as either `Success` or `Failure`.

Comment: Thanks. That was too simple too miss. Sorry for bothering.